# How to know the value entered in the text box if its name or itemid has known

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save the values to the database on save button click. I have a text box with class.The textbox has been repeated for multiple values. I am passing different item id to 
multiple values. when i am clicking the save button. I want to know the value entered in the
textbox. I know the item id here. How can i get that.

Hope you understand my Question

Regards,
Sri

Comment: do u mean that u have the id of the textbox and u want to get its value ?

Answer (score 1):

if you know id then just use like this

```
   $("#id").val()
```

Comment: I dont  know the id. I am creating the text boxes dynamically

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `id` of the attribute, it is straightforward.

```
<input type="text" value="4" id="txt_4"/>
```

jQuery

```
var val = $('#txt_4').val();
alert(val);
```

---

If your dom looks like this, and you don't have `id` attribute specified, here's how you get the details:

```
<input type="text" value="1"/>
<input type="text" value="2"/>
<input type="text" value="3"/>
<input type="text" value="4"/> <!-- Get this value. -->
<input type="text" value="5"/>
<input type="text" value="6"/>
```

jQuery

```
var val = $('input').eq(3).val(); // The count starts from 0
alert(val);
```

Comment: Hi i am creating the text boxes dynamically and i am assigning the values in to the item id